# Setting up Dependency Injection for Two Storage account in an Azure Application

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, containers, azure-storage-account

I have an application which i would like to make reference to two different storage accounts (SA1 and SA2) which both has a single contaner each "container1" and "container2" respectively. I have the below DI setup for both (Not sure this is correct)

```
        serviceCollection.AddAzureClients(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddBlobServiceClient("SA1_connectionStr"))
            .WithVersion(BlobClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2019_02_02);

       builder.AddBlobServiceClient("SA2_connectionStr"))
            .WithVersion(BlobClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2019_02_02);

    });
```

When i use the "blobContainer" reference (using the code below) it's only refering the container in the "SA2" storgaeAccount (maybe bcause it was added last in the DI setup)

```
 private readonly BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient;
 var blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container2);
```

How do i make reference to storageAccount SA1 and storageAccount SA2 seperately?

Comment: You have here example in the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/dependency-injection?tabs=web-app-builder

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to the name the clients in order to differentiate them:

```
   serviceCollection.AddAzureClients(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddBlobServiceClient("SA1_connectionStr"))
            .WithName("SA1")
            .WithVersion(BlobClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2019_02_02);

       builder.AddBlobServiceClient("SA2_connectionStr"))
            .WithName("SA2")
            .WithVersion(BlobClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2019_02_02);

    });
```

and then you can access them by injecting:

```
IAzureClientFactory<BlobServiceClient> clientFactory
```

into your constructor and then

```
_sa1Client = clientFactory.CreateClient("SA1");
_sa2Client = clientFactory.CreateClient("SA2");
```

and then use those clients to actually interact with the different containers.

You can checkout the [official documentation for this here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/dependency-injection?tabs=web-app-builder#configure-multiple-service-clients-with-different-names)

Answer (score 1):

alternitive to akseli

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddBlobServiceClient("SA1", options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionString = "your_connection_string_here_1";
            });

            services.AddBlobServiceClient("SA2", options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionString = "your_connection_string_here_2";
            });

            // Other service registrations...
        }

        // Other methods...
    }
```

```
public class YourService
    {
        private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobClientSA1;
        private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobClientSA2;

        public YourService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Inject the specific instance you want
            _blobClientSA1 = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<BlobServiceClient>("SA1");
                _blobClientSA2 = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<BlobServiceClient>("SA2");
        }

        // Use _blobClient as needed...
    }
```